# Convergence of $\sum_{\rho} |\Gamma(\rho)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

In [his proof](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa18/aa18110.pdf) of the prime number theorem Littlewood claims that the sum $\sum_{\rho} |\Gamma(\rho)|$ converges, where ${\rho}$ ranges over the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta$ counting multiplicity.

I guess this can be proven using Stirling's formula and a result on the growth of the modulus of zeros of $\zeta$.

Most of the results in this direction that I have seen are claims on $n(T)= \sharp(\zeta^{-1}(\{ 0\})\cap \{ z\in \mathbb C,\, |z-1/2| < T \})$, with $T>0$. For instance, from Jensen's formula, one has $n(T) \leq 3T \log T$ for $T\gg 0$. I do not see how can one derive a proof of the convergence of the aforementioned sum using such bounds.

Does such proof exist or do you know any result of the form $|\rho_k|\geq f(k)$ where $(\rho_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ are the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta$ ordered by modulus counting multiplicty which is sufficient to prove the convergence ?

Comment: between $N$ and $N+1$ there are at most $c \log N$ zeroes with ordinate there, let's call their set $S_N$, while the abscissas are in $[0,1]$ so for $N$ large enough we have $\sum_{\rho \in  S_N} |\Gamma(\rho)| \le K \sqrt {N+1} \log N e^{-\pi N/2}$ so clearly the series converges

Comment: From Riemann-von Mangoldt formula, there is $|\rho_n|\sim2\pi n/\log n$.